# SQL Group Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
Date           County       Location
2020-01-01     abc           west
2020-01-02     abc           north
2020-02-01     xzy           west
2020-02-02     xzy           east
2020-02-03     xyz           east
```

Can we group and count so it can become

```
County    jan     feb
abc        2       
xyz               3

Location  jan    feb 
west       1
north      1
west              1
east              2
```

Thank you

Comment: I think will need pivot to make it woks but no experience with pivot

Comment: @Tsang there are three countries `abc`,  ` xzy` and `xyz`. See the updated answer with the live demo link. You need to correct either your input or the desired output as per the data given by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as the base query and then write a pivot query based on this query result as shown in the demo link.

For your reference [FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
Select country
  , FORMAT([date], 'MMMM') as Month
  , count(*) as Tot
from YourTable
group by country, FORMAT([date], 'MMMM')
```

Pivot query needed an aggregate function. Here is the complete query.

```
create table YourTable
([Date] Date
, Country varchar(20)
, Location varchar(20))

insert into YourTable values
('2020-01-01', 'abc', 'west'),
('2020-01-02', 'abc', 'north'),
('2020-02-01', 'xzy', 'west'),
('2020-02-02', 'xzy', 'east'),
('2020-02-03', 'xyz', 'east')

Select * into #temp from(
Select country
  , FORMAT([date], 'MMMM') as Month
  , count(*) as Tot
from YourTable
group by country, FORMAT([date], 'MMMM')
)a

--Select * from #temp

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Month) 
            FROM #temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT country, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Country
                    , Month
                    , Tot
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Tot)
                for Month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23cd5bfaa6b14d4e88de0455ddab0eaa) demo.

Comment: Can we get dt by  each column by  month

Comment: I works but why we have 2 results. Can we keep the second one only?

Comment: @Tsang Please check with the link now it has been already updated. First one was just a select statement of the base query which has been commented.

Comment: @Tsang run a query `drop table #temp` first and then run the entire query.

Comment: I got it need to drop #temp

Comment: Wonderful. Look so simple but not. Thank you and I owe you a cup of coffee.

Comment: One quick question, how to we do column month in order?

Comment: @Tsang . . . This is not simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation along with `grouping sets`:

```
select county, location,
       sum(case when date >= '2020-01-01' and date < '2020-02-01' then 1 end) as jan,
       sum(case when date >= '2020-02-01' and date < '2020-03-01' then 1 end) as feb
from t
group by grouping sets ( (country), (location) );
```

Comment: Wow, this queries look more easier. Thank you

Comment: Can we replace null  to 0

Comment: @tsang . . . If you want zeros instead of NULLs, then that should be in the question.